# CGAL: How do I rotate one 3D vector onto another?

Tags: rotation, vector-graphics, cgal

I'm attempting to rotate a 3D, non-unit vector (Vector_3) so that it is coincident with another 3D non-unit vector using the Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel.

I'm creating the rotation matrix mostly refering to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180418/calculate-rotation-matrix-to-align-vector-a-to-vector-b-in-3d). However creating unit vectors is non-trivial. What is the most appropriate method for performing such a rotation with this kernel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as you need `sqrt`, you will only be able to get an approximation. I suggest that you use [`CGAL::Cartesian_converter`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Kernel_23/classCGAL_1_1Cartesian__converter.html) to do the operation in a Kernel that support `sqrt` (like `CGAL::Simple_cartesian<double>` if no exact predicate is needed) and then convert the result back to EPEC kernel.